# Can't get REST WS to work with Netbeans

Tags: java, tomcat, jpa, netbeans, jndi

I was following the tutorial on the web site of [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html), but can't get it to work. I posted the relevant files in a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/64378d2091e4e274ec7a). I selected a maven project, Tomcat 7 and Java 5EE (because Java 6EE apparently doesn't work with Tomcat 7)

When following the tutorial I created a database with a "user" table and Netbeans could connect to the database and create the necessary files, so there's nothing wrong with my database. When I run the web application it shows the default index.jsp page, so the web server also works.

If I try to access one of the resources (http://localhost:8084/test3/resources/com.mycompany.test3.user/count) I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name persistence-factory is not bound in this Context
    service.UserRESTFacade.getJpaController(UserRESTFacade.java:33)
    service.UserRESTFacade.count(UserRESTFacade.java:97)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)    
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
```

From what I can tell the persistence.xml looks right and the name is referenced in the Java files, so I don't have an idea of where to start. As mentioned, the files are available as a GIST (see links at the top)

I'm running version 7 of both Netbeans and Tomcat if that helps

Answer (score 0):

This error means that your application tried to look up the data source in JNDI and failed. JNDI is a method of providing configurations to an app that are tied to the app container, and it's most often used for configuring database connections.

Search for "Tomcat JNDI JPA" and you should get some useful information.

### EDIT:

OK, I took a closer look at your code. I'm actually not sure why the JNDI lookup is failing, but since you're set up for application-managed connections, you should be able to skip JNDI altogether and get the factory like this:

```
// use the name specified in persistence.xml
javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("com.mycompany_test3_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU")
```

Another thing: creating an EntityManagerFactory is expensive, so you should only do it once. The way you have it now, you're creating one on every transaction, which will be horribly inefficient. What I'd do is create it at application start-up, then store it somewhere like the ServletContext.

Comment: Shouldn't persistence.xml + web.xml take care of that?